# get wrong output when remove item from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, array-splice

I want remove one item from my array. For example i want remove "Apple" from array. The code like below :

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(2,1);
```

When i run this code, the output is ["Apple"]. The output should be ["Banana", "Orange", "Mango"]. Please help me to find what wrong with my code?

Comment: output is `["Banana", "Orange", "Mango"]`, check the value of `fruits`. You might be looking at the return value of `splice`.

Comment: splice returns the plucked element from the array, check the array itself and it would have been modified.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: The output is `["Apple"]` because i try to `console.log(fruits.splice(2,1))` and like all you say it return value of splice not the value of array. After that i try `console('fruits')` and it's return `["Banana", "Orange", "Mango"]`. Thanks for the solution @gurvinder372 @js_noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but yes, you must be taking extract from that splice, instead you need to take actual array as is.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(2,1);
console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I use `console.log(fruits.splice(2,1))` with expected the result of array. But now i know if it just return the value of splice. Once again thanks for you contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s).
This link could help you: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp